# How to create a geometry using a variant

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-geometry

Is it possible to define a `boost::geometry` object using a `boost::variant` ?

This code doesn't compile as it doesn't like the variant object used inside `geom::read_wkt()`.

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/linestring.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/variant/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

namespace geom = boost::geometry;

typedef geom::model::d2::point_xy<double> point_type;
typedef geom::model::linestring<point_type> linestring_type;
typedef geom::model::polygon<point_type> polygon_type;

typedef boost::variant
  <
    point_type,
    linestring_type,
    polygon_type,
  > 
  geometryVariant;

int main() {
  std::string wkt = "LINESTRING(0 0, 1 1, 2, 2)";
  geometryVariant gv;
  geom::read_wkt(wkt, gv);
  return 0;
}
```

However, if I explicitly define the `linestring_type` it works fine

```
int main() {
  std::string wkt = "LINESTRING(0 0, 1 1, 2, 2)";
  linestring_type ls;
  geom::read_wkt(wkt, ls);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Copy&paste the error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're swimming against the design of the library. If you want a runtime-polymorphic geometry type, use one.

Of course you can *build* one on top of Boost Geometry using variants. So, let's assume you want to do this.

As always with variants, to operate on them generically, you require a visitor to visit the potential element types:

```
struct {
    using result_type = bool;

    template <typename... T>
        bool operator()(std::string const& wkt, boost::variant<T...>& geo) const {
            return boost::apply_visitor(boost::bind(*this, boost::ref(wkt), _1), geo);
        }

    template <typename Geo>
        bool operator()(std::string const& wkt, Geo& geo) const {
            try {
                geom::read_wkt(wkt, geo);
                return true;
            } catch(geom::read_wkt_exception const& cant) {
                return false;
            }
        }

} read_wkt;
```

Now you can

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b72dae6a750c4182)</kbd>**

```
int main() {
    std::string wkt = "LINESTRING(0 0, 1 1, 2, 2)";
    geometryVariant gv = linestring_type{};
    if (read_wkt(wkt, gv))
        std::cout << geom::wkt(gv);
}
```

Printing:

```
LINESTRING(0 0,1 1,2 0,2 0)
```

### Further thoughts

This might not do what you expect. If you had just a default-constructed variant, it would not have worked, because the visitor will visit the current state (which is `point_type`) and [it would fail](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/00f1c0265ded2996).

To actually get a dynamic read method that detects the geometry type from the input, you could:

```
geometryVariant read_any_wkt(std::string const& wkt) {
    { linestring_type tmp; if (read_wkt(wkt, tmp)) return tmp; }
    { point_type      tmp; if (read_wkt(wkt, tmp)) return tmp; }
    { polygon_type    tmp; if (read_wkt(wkt, tmp)) return tmp; }
    throw geom::read_wkt_exception("read_any_wkt failed", wkt);
}
```

Which works: **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f911fb26dc5354ab)</kbd>**

```
int main() {
    for (std::string const wkt : {
        "LINESTRING(0 0, 1 1, 2 2)",
        "POINT(0 0)",
        "POLYGON((0 0, 1 1, 2 2, 0 0))", })
    {
        {
            geometryVariant gv;
            if (read_wkt(wkt, gv))
                std::cout << "read_wkt: " << geom::wkt(gv) << "\n";
        }

        auto any = read_any_wkt(wkt);
        std::cout << "read_any_wkt: " << geom::wkt(any) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
read_any_wkt: LINESTRING(0 0,1 1,2 2)
read_wkt: POINT(0 0)
read_any_wkt: POINT(0 0)
read_any_wkt: POLYGON((0 0,1 1,2 2,0 0))
```

### Bonus: Make That Generic

That's a quite a bit more work, sadly:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru (c++14 used)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/781a99e637379630)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/fusion/include/accumulate.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/vector.hpp>
struct read_any_wkt_t {
    geometryVariant operator()(std::string const& wkt) const {
        geometryVariant output;
        call_impl(wkt, output);
        return output;
    }

    private:
    template <typename... T>
        static void call_impl(std::string const& wkt, boost::variant<T...>& output) {
            boost::fusion::vector<T...> candidates;
            bool success = boost::fusion::accumulate(candidates, false, [&wkt, &output](bool success, auto candidate) {
                if (!success && read_wkt(wkt, candidate)) {
                    output = candidate;
                    return true;
                }
                return success;
            });

            if (!success) throw geom::read_wkt_exception("read_any_wkt failed", wkt);
        }
} read_any_wkt;
```

Printing the same output.

### BONUS BONUS

Instead of blindly trying to parse WKT until an exception isn't thrown, a better way to deserialize from WKT would be to actually parse the type id first and switch on that.

For that I've drawn up a sample using Boost Spirit X3 to switch the output to the type associated with the leading type keyword.

Parsing becomes simpler:

```
template <typename... T>
    static void call_impl(std::string const& wkt, boost::variant<T...>& output) {
        static auto const switch_ = gen_switch(output);
        if (parse(wkt.begin(), wkt.end(), switch_, output)) {
            boost::apply_visitor(boost::bind(read_any_helper{}, boost::ref(wkt), _1), output);
        } else {
            throw geom::read_wkt_exception("Unregistered type", wkt);
        }
    }
```

The `gen_switch` call generates a Trie containing the supportable geometry types only once.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/719244ecfe75f36c)</kbd>**

*Note this adds some types, validity diagnostics and auto-correction*

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/linestring.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/multi_linestring.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/multi_polygon.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace geom = boost::geometry;
namespace bgm = geom::model;

#include <boost/fusion/include/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

namespace detail {
    template <typename Variant> struct read_any_helper {

        static Variant call(std::string const& wkt) {
            Variant output;
            call_impl(wkt, output);
            return output;
        }

        using result_type = void;
        template <typename Geo> result_type operator()(std::string const& wkt, Geo& output) const {
            geom::read_wkt(wkt, output);
        }

      private:
        template <typename... T>
            static void call_impl(std::string const& wkt, boost::variant<T...>& output) {
                static auto const switch_ = gen_switch(output);
                if (parse(wkt.begin(), wkt.end(), switch_, output)) {
                    boost::apply_visitor(boost::bind(read_any_helper{}, boost::ref(wkt), _1), output);
                } else {
                    throw geom::read_wkt_exception("Unregistered type", wkt);
                }
            }

        template <typename... T>
            static auto gen_switch(boost::variant<T...> const&) {
                namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
                x3::symbols<Variant> result;

                boost::fusion::for_each(boost::fusion::vector<T...>{}, [&result](auto&& seed) {
                    auto const serialized = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(geom::wkt(seed));

                    std::string keyword;
                    if (x3::parse(serialized.begin(), serialized.end(), +x3::alpha, keyword))
                        result.add(keyword, std::forward<decltype(seed)>(seed));
                    else
                        throw std::logic_error(std::string("registering WKT for ") + typeid(seed).name());
                });

                result.for_each([](auto& key, auto&&...) {
                        std::cout << "DEBUG: statically registered support for " << key << " type\n";
                    });

                return result;
            }
    };
}

using point_type = bgm::d2::point_xy<double>;

typedef boost::variant<
        point_type,
        bgm::linestring<point_type>,
        bgm::multi_linestring<bgm::linestring<point_type> >,
        bgm::polygon<point_type>,
        bgm::multi_polygon<bgm::polygon<point_type> >
    > AnyGeo;

template <typename Variant = AnyGeo>
Variant read_any_wkt(std::string const& wkt) {
    return detail::read_any_helper<Variant>::call(wkt);
}

int main() {
    for (auto wkt : {
        "LINESTRING(0 0, 1 1, 2 2)",
        "POINT(0 0)",
        "POLYGON((0 0, 1 1, 2 2))",
        "POLYGON((0 0, 1 1, 2 2, 0 0))",
        "MULTIPOLYGON(((0 0, 1 1, 2 2, 1 2, 0 0)))",
    }) {
        AnyGeo any = read_any_wkt(wkt);
        std::cout << "read_any_wkt: " << geom::wkt(any) << "\n";

        std::string reason;
        if (!geom::is_valid(any, reason)) {
            std::cout << reason << "\n";

            geom::correct(any);
            std::cout << " -- attempted correction: " << geom::wkt(any) << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Printing

```
DEBUG: statically registered support for LINESTRING type
DEBUG: statically registered support for MULTILINESTRING type
DEBUG: statically registered support for MULTIPOLYGON type
DEBUG: statically registered support for POINT type
DEBUG: statically registered support for POLYGON type
read_any_wkt: LINESTRING(0 0,1 1,2 2)
read_any_wkt: POINT(0 0)
read_any_wkt: POLYGON((0 0,1 1,2 2,0 0))
Geometry has too few points
 -- attempted correction: POLYGON((0 0,1 1,2 2,0 0))
read_any_wkt: POLYGON((0 0,1 1,2 2,0 0))
Geometry has spikes. A spike point was found with apex at (2, 2)
 -- attempted correction: POLYGON((0 0,1 1,2 2,0 0))
read_any_wkt: MULTIPOLYGON(((0 0,1 1,2 2,1 2,0 0)))
Geometry has wrong orientation
 -- attempted correction: MULTIPOLYGON(((0 0,1 2,2 2,1 1,0 0)))
```

Comment: Awesome work sehe. I'm going to need some time to digest and apply it, but I should be able to accept it as an answer soon.

Comment: A better way to deserialize from WKT would be to actually parse the type id first and switch on that: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/719244ecfe75f36c)**. Note this adds some types, validity diagnostics and auto-correction